# RabbitMQ starts on a different port every time?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I am running rabbitmq servers over Ec2. I am trying to create a cluster, and have the ports: 4369 and 25672 and 5672 open as specified in the rabbitmq docs : https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

Whenever I start my rabbitmq server:

```
rabbitmq-server -detached
```

The server starts on a different port. Output of epmd -names gives:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name rabbit at port 50696
```

Where '50696' changes each time I stop the server and start it again. This is making it impossible for me to cluster my instances without allowing all ports inbound on my aws firewall rules.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ec2.html

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq.config:

```
[
    {kernel,
    [
        {inet_dist_listen_min, 55555},
        {inet_dist_listen_max, 55560}
    ]}
].
```

epmd -names

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name rabbit at port 55555
```